# Page source not updating after clicking dropdown selenium python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

Page source is not getting updated. Beautiful soup is taking the page source after `python_button.click()` and not after `py_button.click()`. I want the page source to be selected after clicking the `dropdown` option. Please help me with how to resolve this.

```py
python_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href='/CitingArticles.do?product=WOS&SID=8B2ggJlEbmGqTLqT8Wq&search_mode=CitingArticles&parentProduct=WOS&parentQid=2&parentDoc=1&REFID=57952433&logEventUT=WOS:000231266300001&excludeEventConfig=ExcludeIfFromNonInterProduct']")
python_button.click()
py_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='selectPageSize_bottom']/option[@value='50']")
py_button.click()


soup=BeautifulSoup(urlopen(driver.current_url), 'lxml')
table = soup.find("div", {"class": "search-results"})


inf=table.find_all("div",{"class": "search-results-content"})
for val in inf:
    titles=val.find_all('value')
    authors=val.find_all('a')

    for title in titles:
        if 'lang_id' in str(title):
            print(title.get_text())

    for author in authors:
        if 'title="Find more records by this author"' in str(author):
            print(author.get_text()+";")
```

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am unable to get the updated page source after clicking the dropdown from selenium. It shows 50 options in the browser after performing selenium dropdown click, but when I print the options it only prints 10. I hope this information is clear

Answer (score 0):

I added a quick Thread.sleep(2000); and the page source was updated. My page had javascript that needed a moment to load. If that works consider WebDriverWait vs. sleep.